# Movie/telefilm in which a princess needed true love's kiss to revive from a poisonous apple

Tags: story-identification, movie

I don't remember when I watched this movie or telefilm, but I remember few details of it:

- The setting was modern i.e. 21st century or late 20th century, but the princess didn't belong to this time. Either she was from the past or another dimension.
- The princess needed to attend a party, but she didn't have proper party dress by modern standards. She was assisted by a little girl (age less than 10). I remember her funny statement clearly: "My dad told me to use it only during emergency and this is an emergency." (she had pulled out credit card out of closet).
- In the party, an evil woman offered the princess an apple which turned out to be poisonous. Upon eating, the princess became unconscious and she had until 12 o'clock midnight. She could be saved only by true love's kiss.

Comment: One of these? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Films_based_on_Snow_White

Comment: Sounds like [Enchanted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchanted_(film))... but I don't have time to make this a real answer.

Comment: Knew this right away from the credit card joke.  That stuck with me too - good point to put in the description.

Comment: @Randal'Thor My first thought when I saw this in HNQ was "Lots of them."

Comment: I immediately thought "snow white" when I saw the title, and I was coming to write an answer about it until I saw the question itself 

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This is the Disney film [*Enchanted*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchanted_(film)).

- Princess comes from another dimension? **Check.**

  [image: The princess from the other dimension falling]
- Little girl has credit card? **Check.**

  [image: The little girl holds up the credit card for the emergency]
- Princess saved by true love's kiss after being poisoned by an apple? **Check.**

  [image: An evil witch holds up the poisoned apple for the princess]
  [image: The princess is saved by a true love's kiss]